# Differentiate this equation. Only variables and constants.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate this equation.

$$y = \frac{At}{Bt^2 + Ct^3}$$

Is this correct?

$$y' = \frac{(Bt^2 + Ct^3) \cdot A - At(2Bt + 3Ct^2)}{(Bt^2 + Ct^3)^2}$$

$$= \frac{ABt^2 + ACt^3 - 2ABt^2 - 3ACt^3}{(Bt^2 + Ct^3)^2}$$

$$= \frac{-ABt^2 - 2ACt^3}{(Bt^2 + Ct^3)^2}$$

Is this as simplified as this equation can get?

Comment: You can divide both numerator and denominator by $t^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your derivative is all correct, though you have some more algebraic simplification that you can do:

$$\frac{-ABt^2 - 2ACt^3}{(Bt^2 + Ct^3)^2}$$

Let's first factor the numerator.

$$-ABt^2 - 2ACt^3 = -At^2(B+2Ct)$$

And now the denominator.

$$(Bt^2+Ct^3)^2 = (t^2(B+Ct))^2 = t^4(B+Ct)^2 $$

We've got the $t^2$ like term that we can reduce:

$$\frac{-At^2(B+2Ct)}{t^4(B+Ct)^2} = \frac{-A(B+2Ct)}{t^2(B+Ct)^2}$$

We have no more ways to reduce like terms, so the final reduced answer is:

$$ -\frac{A(B+2Ct)}{t^2(B+Ct)^2} $$